# Range operator; flip but prevent flop, and make immediate flip

Tags: perl

```
perl -wle 'print join " ", grep /3/ .. undef(), 1..10'
```

outputs `3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

`Q1`: Is there better way than `undef` to prevent flop?

`Q2`: How to force left part of range operator to unconditional `true` (ie. `true .. /7/`)?

UPDATE:

```
perl -wE 'say join " ", grep { ((/7/ .. undef)||1) ==1 } 1..10'
```

could be used as `true .. /7/` replacement.

Comment: What does `1 .. /7/` have to do with your question?

Comment: @TLP `1` should be `always true` => make immediate flip.

Comment: @TLP, `1` means `$.==1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Any false expression that isn't constant-folded to a number will do.

   ```
   perl -wE'say join " ", grep $_==3 .. undef, 1..10'

   perl -wE'say join " ", grep $_==3 .. do{0}, 1..10'

   perl -wE'say our $FALSE; say join " ", grep $_==3 .. $FALSE, 1..10'
   ```

   Without a flip-flop.

   ```
   perl -wE'my $ok; say join " ", grep $ok ||= $_==3, 1..10'
   ```
2. If you want the boolean opposite of something, use negation!

   ```
   perl -wE'say join " ", grep !($_==8 .. undef), 1..10'
   ```

   Without a flip-flop.

   ```
   perl -wE'my $done; say join " ", grep !($done ||= $_==8), 1..10'
   ```

   Ok, so I changed `7` to `8`. To actually match on `7`,

   ```
   perl -wE'my $last; say join " ", grep { my $x = ($_==7 .. undef); !$x || $x == 1 } 1..10'
   ```

   Without a flip-flop.

   ```
   perl -wE'my $done; say join " ", grep { my $rv = $done; $done ||= $_==7; !$rv } 1..10'
   ```

Comment: This is great, but it feels like cheating since you know that `8` goes after `7`.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't go without external var. Btw, output should start with `7`.

Comment: I think that this could be cleaned up: `perl -wE'say join " ", grep { my $x = ($_==7 .. undef); !$x or $x == 1 } 1..10'`

Comment: Sure, there other ways. Still more complicated than not using a flip-flop. Not using a flip-flop means you can also last/return/die safely even if the flip-flop is in code that will be called again.

Answer (score 2):

## Q1

Use the `*FAIL` verb:

```
print join " ", grep /3/ .. /(*FAIL)/, 1 .. 10;
```

Which can be abbreviated to just `*F`:

```
print join " ", grep /3/ .. /(*F)/, 1 .. 10;
```

And for the [TIMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it):

```
print join " ", grep /3/ .. /(?!)/, 1 .. 10;
```

Comment: Not sure if it is better alternative, as regex gets constantly applied against `$_`, unlike `undef`?

Comment: @JohnC There Is More Than One Way To Do It, a Perl aphorism.

Comment: Aaaah of course!  Are there any more verbs? other than *F?